# How to reduce the size of kernel?

Tags: kernel

I want to delete some modules from my kernel so that the size of vmlinuz is reduced to 1mb in such a way that the kernel doesn't crash and it still works.

Comment: While this is possible, you need to have advanced knowledge of kernel configuration. What compression algorithm do you use?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27080347/how-can-i-reduce-the-size-of-linux-kernel

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can resize the kernel to 1 mb - however, the [Kernel Size Tuning Guide](http://elinux.org/Kernel_Size_Tuning_Guide) shows you which config options have which effect in respect to modifying the size of the Kernel.

General information about how to build the kernel on your own (which is what you need to do) can be found at [the according howto at Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel). Further help on the details about Kernel compilation can be found at the [Kernel compile page at Ubuntu help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Kernel/Compile).